# How to extract only elements with key prefixed by a string efficiently in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, performance

I need a function, that takes an `$array` and returns it with only the elements, where the key is prefixed by a a given `$prefix`. The keys of the result array should *not* contain the prefix. Here is the unit test, that the method has to pass:

```
class ArrayProcessorTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider provideDataForExtractElementsWithKeyPrefixedByString
     */
    public function testExtractElementsWithKeyPrefixedByString($testArray, $prefix, $expectedResult)
    {
        $this->assertEquals($expectedResult, $this->arrayProcessor->extractElementsWithKeyPrefixedByString($testArray, $prefix));
    }
}

public function provideDataForExtractElementsWithKeyPrefixedByString()
{
    $data = [];
    $testArray = [
        'foo__qwe' => '123', 'bar__asd' => '234', 'baz__yxc' => '345', 'buz__lmn' => '456',
        'foo__qsc' => '567', 'bar__wsx' => '678', 'baz__edc' => '789', 'buz__rfv' => '890',
    ];
    $prefixes = [
        'singlePrefixFoo' => 'foo__',
        'arrayPrefixBarBuz' => ['bar__', 'buz__',]
    ];
    $expectedResults = [
        'singlePrefixFoo' => ['qwe' => '123', 'qsc' => '567',],
        'arrayPrefixBarBuz' => ['asd' => '234', 'wsx' => '678', 'lmn' => '456', 'rfv' => '890',]
    ];
    $data = [
        [$testArray, $prefixes['singlePrefixFoo'], $expectedResults['singlePrefixFoo']],
        [$testArray, $prefixes['arrayPrefixBarBuz'], $expectedResults['arrayPrefixBarBuz']]
    ];
    return $data;
}
```

Here my variant of the method:

```
class ArrayProcessor
{
    public function extractElementsWithKeyPrefixedByString(array $array, $prefix)
    {
        $filteredArray = [];
        if (is_string($prefix)) {
            array_walk($array, function($value, $keyName) use($prefix, &$filteredArray) {
                if (strpos($keyName, $prefix) === 0) {
                    $filteredArray[str_replace($prefix, '', $keyName)] = $value;
                }
            });
        } elseif (is_array($prefix)) {
            foreach ($prefix as $currentPrefix) {
                $filteredArray = array_merge(
                    $filteredArray, $this->extractElementsWithKeyPrefixedByString($array, $currentPrefix)
                );
            }
        }
        return $filteredArray;
    }
}
```

**How to make this method more efficient?**

Comment: The text reads *"The keys of the result array should contain the prefix"* but the expected results in the test case contain the keys **without** the prefix. I guess the test case is right (it matches the code and it passes).

Comment: @axiac Thank you for the hint. I've now corrected the text. The the result array's keys should _not_ contain the prefix(-es).

Comment: imo, To find out how efficient the different methods are then the only way to do that is to benchmark them. Just guessing as to what code PHP is using and which is more efficient is not obvious from looking at the code.

Comment: @RyanVincent You are right, but measuring is another topic. Anyway, I've just added xDebug callgraphs comparison to my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39745578/2019043).

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
$array = ['foo__x' => 1, 'foo__y' => 2, 'bar__z' => 3, 'baz' => 42];
// For other test arrays and prefixes (of type `string` and `array`) s. the unit test in the question.

public function extractElementsWithKeyPrefixedByString(array $array, $prefix)
{
    if (is_array($prefix)) {
        $prefix = implode('|', $prefix);
    }
    $iterator = new \RegexIterator(
        new \ArrayIterator($array),
        '~^(' . $prefix . ')([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$~',
        \RegexIterator::REPLACE,
        \RegexIterator::USE_KEY
    );
    $iterator->replacement = '$2';

    return iterator_to_array($iterator);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [x] => 1
    [y] => 2
    [z] => 3
)
```

It performs a about `10%` better than the original code (for a case with `string` and `array` prefixes):

xDebug callgraph **before** (for the original code):

[image: xDebug callgraph before]

xDebug callgraph **after**:

[image: xDebug callgraph after]

Note that removing the prefixes is not necessarily a good idea. If you got `foo__x` and `bar__x` and remove both, "foo__" and "bar__", only the last x will make it to the resulting array, e.g. the value of `foo__x` will be overwritten by `bar__x`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's actually faster than the original code, but still not as fast as [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39745578/2019043). I will now edit your answer and add the xDebug callgraph.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
$output = preg_grep('!^foo__!', $array);
```

or

```
$output = preg_grep('/foo__(\w+)/', $array);
```

or for multiple prefixes:

```
$output = preg_grep('/(foo|bar|baz)__(\w+)/', $array);
```

Please see for more informations:

- [preg_grep](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-grep.php)

Answer (score 0):

I could now *significantly* increase the performance by using the [`preg_filter(...)`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-filter.php) ans some native array manipulating functions:

```
public function extractElementsWithKeyPrefixedByString(array $array, $prefix)
{
    $filteredArray = [];
    if (is_array($prefix)) {
        $prefix = implode('|', $prefix);
    }
    $filteredKeys = preg_filter(['/(' . $prefix . ')([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/'], ['$2'], array_keys($array));
    $arrayValues = array_values($array);
    $filteredValues = array_intersect_key($arrayValues, $filteredKeys);
    $filteredArray = array_combine($filteredKeys, $filteredValues);
    return $filteredArray;
}
```

xDebug callgraph **before**:

[image: xDebug callgraph before]

xDebug callgraph **after**:

[image: xDebug callgraph after]

A disadvantage of this solution is, that I have to explicitly set the regex for the part of array key after the `$prefix` (here `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+` -- it's not    complete!). But it's at least faster (much, much faster!) than the original variant.